# Can't Install latest version of Cocoapods

Tags: swift, ruby, xcode, command-line, cocoapods

I'm not sure how, but I managed to install version `1.8.4` of cocoapods. However, I can't update it. I need to update it because the pods for the firebase google sign in require `FirebaseAnalytics`, and `Firebase Analytics` requires cocoapods to be 1.10.0. Whenever I try to update it, either by simply `sudo gem install cocoapods` or `sudo gem update cocoapods`, I get the following error:

`The compiler failed to generate an executable file. (RuntimeError) You have to install development tools first.`

This is odd because I do in fact have xcode developer tools installed.

[image]

And here are the pods (one of which requires `FirebaseAnalytics`)

[image]

Also see the error message:

[image]

This question is similar to [several](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39481636/updating-to-latest-version-of-cocoapods) [others](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27768420/gem-installation-error-you-have-to-install-development-tools-first)--I'm asking a new question because the answers to those questions didn't help me and the questions were fairly old, so I doubt I'll get any help there.

I greatly appreciate your help. This problem alone is stopping me from using Firebase's google sign in in my application.

EDIT:
After I re-installed `cocoapods` with `brew` I checked my pod version, only to find that it was still 1.8.4. I then ran `brew upgrade cocoapods` and everything seemingly looked up to date. But I checked the version once more and am still seeing 1.8.4. What is going on here?

[image]

EDIT 2: bundle result

I was able to successfully (seemingly) install bundle, but I'm getting errors when I try to use bundle to install / update cocoapods.

[image]

EDIT 3: Solution Found?

I tried upgrading cocoapods again with brew, and for some reason it worked this time--even though last time I tried upgrading cocoapods with brew it didn't work. (Did bundle help?) I still have yet to see if this solves my original problem, but cocoapods is now version `1.11.2`, the newest version. Thanks for all the help!

[image]

Comment: FirebaseAuth does not require FirebaseAnalytics.

Comment: You may be right, but certainly one of the pods I need for google sign in with firebase does. See my clarified question.

Comment: `Firebase/Core` is deprecated and just a synonym for `Firebase/Analytics`

Comment: If I change `Firebase/Core` to `Firebase/Analytics` will that fix my problem?

Comment: Nope, the OP said only FirebaseAuth was needed, but if you need Analytics, you need to update CocoaPods.

Comment: If you're not already, use https://bundler.io/ to manage your ruby gems (including cocoapods) and use a `Gemfile` to manage your Cocoapods version. see this post for more: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66395480/1014164

Comment: See edits to post. Did I use the `Gemfile` incorrectly? I followed the commands in the post you linked.

Comment: WIth `brew`, I'd check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3987683/homebrew-install-specific-version-of-formula to install correct version. There is the `brew switch` for instance if you checked correctly the version. Your issue is there I think... Because I think that the 1.11.2_1 is installed, but it's not the one "linked"... See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13477363/how-can-i-brew-link-a-specific-version

Comment: Brew ended up working (at least in updating cocoapods). See my edited post. I have yet to see if this solves my actual problem, but thanks for all the help anyways!

Answer (score -2):

Updated answer.

- Install cocapods with brew.

I was facing same issue that installed latest version cocapods with brew but when try to check in terminal my machine always linking old version cocapods so here i bellow commands resolve my issue.

**Override brew pods to another pods**

```
brew link --overwrite cocoapods
```

Comment: I tried that command. Didn’t work.

Comment: try this  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61496402/cocoapods-stopped-installing-firebase-analytics-with-error

Comment: For the google sign in, I do believe that I need to use cocoapods--I couldn't find it on SPM and it specifically says to use cocoapods. The stack overflow question you linked to is related to my problem, but didn't address my issue. The answers have to do with the firebase version, but I need to update cocoapods.

Comment: No the point is that I already tried updating cocoapods--that's exactly the error I'm having. I tried `sudo gem install cocoapods` and `sudo gem update cocoapods` and both gave the error I described above. Is there another way of updating cocoapods that you suggest?

Comment: Try this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64235993/error-installing-cocoapods-macos-bigsur

Comment: Ok, I used `brew` as suggested in one of the answers to install `cocoapods`. However, it appears that the version is still `1.8.4`. I'm going to try using `brew` to update `cocoapods` next...

Comment: try this commands this command i was facing same issue - brew link --overwrite cocoapods